# Show who is responsible for which line after in a git project

Tags: git, git-commit

I know it's possible to visualize who of the team commited to the project and how many changes they have done.

But is it also possible so analyse all current files of the project and generate a documentation like so you know who did the most for some parts of a file like:

```
User A is responsible for line 1-10
User B is responsible for line 11-30
```

With github or any other platform it's only possible to watch the differences between two commits.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse?  If so, you can _annotate_ each line of code to see who was the most recent author to modify that particular line of code.  You _could_ use `git blame` from the command line to handle this as well, but I much prefer doing this within an IDE.

Comment: like git-blame? "git-blame - Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file" - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

Comment: I think `git blame` is the right one, but is there a tool to generate some html files so I don't have to open every file with the ide to check it?

Comment: What you will get with `git blame` is *who touched each line last*, it does not show you who authored *most* of the line.